# Confidence interval from coefficient and robust standard errors

Tags: regression, stata, robust-standard-error

After having run the following regression in Stata

```
regress y x1 x2 ... xn [weight=w], robust
```

I given the following table:
[image]

Is there a way to get the confidence interval from the coefficient, robust standard errors, and number of observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need the covariances as well.

Take a single covariate model $$ E[y \vert x] = \alpha + \beta x = m(x)$$

The 95%CI for $m(x)$ with a largish sample is $$m(x) \pm 1.96 \cdot SE(m(x))=m(x) \pm 1.96 \cdot \sqrt{SE(\alpha)^2+x^2 \cdot SE(\beta)^2+ 2 \cdot x \cdot Cov(\alpha,\beta)}$$

Stata stores the covariance on the off-diagonal elements of e(V) matrix. You can see it with

```
matrix list e(V)
```

With many covariates, the math gets messy quickly since there are many pairwise covariances. You can avoid doing this by hand by using `margins` or `lincom`.